# MySQL: SELECT the n-th item from an ordered result

Tags: mysql, select

`SELECT`ing the top n elements from a table is easy:

```
SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE pixel_id='some_pixel_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

Finding the n-th element with a subquery is quite straightforward:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM 
    (SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE pixel_id='some_pixel_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000) s;
```

Assuming that there is a `BTREE` index on the relevant columns (`id`), is this approach efficient? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the point of the subquery in your second statement. Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE pixel_id='some_pixel_id' ORDER BY id LIMIT n, 1
```

Comment: precisely what I was thinking so +1 :)

Comment: @david: +1 (althought it's not entirely equivalent). I guess you mean `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT n, 1`

Comment: The "not entirely equivalent" goes to the fact that this will not return the same as the original, if there are fewer than 1000 ids.

Comment: What are the performance considerations?

Answer (score 1):

This is only an improvement over @david's query, so you have the same result when there are less than `1000` rows in the intermediate set:

```
( SELECT id 
  FROM pixels 
  WHERE pixel_id='some_pixel_id' 
  ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 999 
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM pixels 
  WHERE pixel_id='some_pixel_id' 
)
ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

The best index for any of these queries is on `(pixel_id, id)`, not on `(id)` alone.